# creating a generic instance of a class template in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm making a template library in c++. I think it needs to be in the form of a template class because it has to be able to store some data.  I would like to be able to create an instance of that class without having to specify a data type.

Here's what the class template would look like

```
template<class T> 
class MyTemplateClass{
public:
     void saveData(T data);
private:
    T my_data;
};

template<class T> 
void MyTemplateClass<T>::saveData(T data){
    //bunch of code goes here
}
```

and here's how I would like to declare it:

```
class LibraryUser{
public:
    void saveDoubleData(double data);
    void saveFloatData(float data);
private:
    MyTemplateClass<UNKNOWN_TYPE> my_generic_object;
};
```

and use it:

```
void LibraryUser::saveDoubleData(double data){
    my_generic_object.saveData(data);
}

void LibraryUser::saveFloatData(float data){
    my_generic_object.saveData(data);
}
```

What should UNKNOWN_TYPE be? Is this possible?

EXTRA NOTES: I cannot edit the function prototypes of the `LibraryUser` class because it is part of an existing plug-in framework. I'd rather not use template specialization because I don't want to double the code in saveData() since it's actually pretty long.

Comment: _' I cannot edit the structure of the LibraryUser'_ What exactly does this mean?? You're going to create a **framework**, but have already existing client code, you can't change?? That's s.th. that needs to be more elaborate part of the question.

Comment: ok, is that helpful: LibraryUser is actually part of a plug-in framework, so I cannot edit the function prototypes

Comment: If you cannot edit(change) the function prototypes for plugin interfaces, templates wont help to implement these ones. If you can simplify implementation of these interfaces using templates that could be a big deal for future maintenace. Can't really tell without having some more appropriate sample or further information about your context.

Comment: You seem to want a *variant* class. You're not going to solve problem you're attempting to describe here by compile-time template instantiation.

Comment: @WhozCraig, can you elaborate on what you meant by a variant class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the `LibraryUser` class a template as well:

```
template<class T>
class LibraryUser{
public:
    void saveData(T data);
private:
    MyTemplateClass<T> my_generic_object;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use `boost::any` if the type is really unknown, or `boost::variant` if the type is in a specified set of types.

Comment: That doesn't really semantically repoduce, what the OP's showing in his `LibraryUser` application sample.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, true. What the OP is trying to accomplish is hard to guess. I probably guessed wrong. That's why I've added the mention to `boost::any` and `boost::variant`.

Comment: Along that vein I want to mention QVariant from the Qt library as well =).

Comment: I edited the question to mention that I can't change the structure of the LibraryUser class

Comment: Using boost::any sounded exactly like what I wanted, but I'm getting this error: `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'float' to 'boost::any &'`

Comment: @VincentBerthiaume, can I see the code that produces that error? Maybe on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) (that has boost pre installed)?

Comment: @Jefffrey, boost::any works great for the code above (This file can be also found using the Coliru command line: cat /Archive2/63/bdefdabc374e2c/main.cpp). However I can't seem to make it work when I use data as a pointer or buffer (cat /Archive2/ee/ffc89644eff084/main.cpp)

Comment: @VincentBerthiaume, what I meant was [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0eed1e8875b2dcb).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a class member, why not use local instances of your template class?

```
void LibraryUser::saveIntData(float data){
    MyTemplateClass<float> saver;
    saver.saveData(data);
}

void LibraryUser::saveFloatData(int data){
    MyTemplateClass<int> saver;
    saver.saveData(data);
}
```

If `MyTemplateClass` needs s.th. you want to have initialized once (e.g. a database connection), make a class member for that one separately (in `LibraryUser`) and pass a reference to the constructor of `MyTemplateClass`:

```
template<class T> 
class MyTemplateClass{
public:
     MyTemplateClass(DBConnection& conn);
     void saveData(T data);
private:
    T my_data;
    DBConnection& my_conn;
};
```

---

```
class LibraryUser{
public:
    void saveIntData(int data);
    void saveFloatData(float data);
private:
    DBConnection my_conn;
};

void LibraryUser::saveIntData(float data){
    MyTemplateClass<float> saver(my_conn);
    saver.saveData(data);
}
```

About your EXTRA NOTES:

> It is also safe to assume that a given OtherClass object will consistently only call either `saveFloatData` or `saveIntData`, not both.

IMHO that's a bad assumption (restriction) made for client usage, if you're going to design a framework.

**UPDATE:**
Another option I can think of, is to just templating the function in question, not the whole class:

```
class MyGenericClass{
public:
     MyGenericClass();
     template<class T> 
     void saveData(T data);

};
```

Comment: I agree with your comments about my extra notes, I removed that point. I also thought about using 2 objects but that doesn't seem like a particularly clean solution... I'm trying to go for something really generic.

Comment: @VincentBerthiaume _but that doesn't seem like a particularly clean solution_ Why? Enforing usage of RAAI for clients is usually thought as being good design. If you insist then s.th. like `boost::any` or `boost::variant` might be more appropriate for your purpose.

Comment: @VincentBerthiaume ... Enforcing RAII, sorry!

Comment: if the class is not a template, how will I store `T my_data;`?

Comment: May be you need to tell more about the purpose of this particular function? Should that simply be a setter for `my_data` member. What is `my_data`, what are you going to do with it? I didn't recognize the requirement to really have that class member from your sample.

Comment: I'm trying to make a library of audio effects to be used in Steinberg's VST plugin standard. In the VST sdk 2.4, 2 functions are called to process audio samples. One of them, processReplacing, takes in and spits out audio samples encoded with floats. The other one, processDoubleReplacing, does the same with samples encoded in doubles. I'm working on a delay effect, in which I need to save some incoming audio samples in a buffer to add them to later samples. So I need a generic way to use a buffer of either floats or doubles that is progressively filled with incoming float or double samples.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly `saveIntData()` and `saveFloatData()` are the plugin interface methods you need to implement and these are purposed to append single data values to a contigous buffer of either `float` or `int` data. Then you'll **need to have** two separate members. But maybe your sample doesn't really reflect what's the structure/behavior of this plugin interface.

Comment: @VincentBerthiaume If it's true, what I have guessed in my previous comment, the whole thing could boil down to use two `std::vector` members and use either one of them for the interface method implementation. **Also:** Why you're talking about `int` if the plugin interface distinguishes `float` from `double`?? It sounds you're required to implement a method for receiving `float` values, while you're able to backup them as `doubles` in that mysterious _data buffer_, that's just a simple cast, no need for templates in this case (same is true for `int` BTW)!

Answer (score 0):

The template classes are actually different from each other so you can't really change the template type runtime without using some trick. If you don't want to make `LibraryUser` also a template, you can store multiple variables. In this case, if you want to save yourself the trouble of duplicating every code, but you have a limited number of different types just use multiple variables and store which one is actually used. Not really nice, but saves you from making more template classes.

```
class LibraryUser{
public:
    void saveIntData(int data);
    void saveFloatData(float data);
private:
    MyTemplateClass<int> my_int;
    MyTemplateClass<float> my_float;
};
```

Use it:

```
void LibraryUser::saveFloatData(float data){
    my_float.saveData(data);
}

void LibraryUser::saveIntData(int data){
    my_int.saveData(data);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using 2 objects but that doesn't seem like a particularly clean solution... I'm trying to go for something really generic, and I was wondering if it was possible